# External blu-ray drive not working ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, media, blu-ray, optical

I have a generic external Blu-ray drive enclosure I purchased off eBay that I use as my only optical drive. It works just fine on windows, but I can't seem to be able to get it working on Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 1):

I unplugged and reinserted the USB cable and now it works.

Comment: Don't forget, you can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark icon to the left after this has been posted for a couple of days.